# insert multiple lines to script with sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

i'm trying to insert variables before specific line in my script. this is the code  that i'm using:

```
var1=$(echo "database1=")
var2=$(echo "database2=")
var3=$(echo "database3=")

sed -i "/#variables/i \
$var1\
$var2\
$var3" /data1/create_database
```

i expect that `create_database` be like this after i run above command:

```
database1=
database2=
database3=
#variables
```

but i get this result:

```
database1= database2= database3=
#variables
```

tried few ways nothing worked. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need command substitutions to set your variables:

```
var1="database1="
var2="database2="
var3="database3="
```

I think you need single quotes to add newlines, but it looks quite ugly if you quote your variables with double quotes. The double quotes are needed if your variables contain space characters:

```
sed -i '/#variables/i\
'"$var1"'\
'"$var2"'\
'"$var3" /data1/create_database
```

With GNU sed you could simply add a few newlines:

```
sed -i "/#variables/i$var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

Comment: of course i dont need command substitutions. in main script they are out put of command, forgot to fix it. btw, i got an error: `sed: couldn't open temporary file /data1/create_database/sedRtx3Di: Permission denied`. changed the folder permission and error is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an escape sequence (`\n`) to insert newlines. Note that

```
sed -i "/#variables/i \
$var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

is equivalent to

```
sed -i "/#variables/i $var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

so you'd need a double backslash

```
sed -i "/#variables/i\\
$var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

---

Perhaps also consider multiple expressions to make it a single line command, where each expression is effectively a line.

```
sed -i -e '/#variables/i\' -e "$var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

And finally you might need to escape your variables

```
var1=$(echo "database1=" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^&[]/\\&/g')
var2=$(echo "database2=" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^&[]/\\&/g')
var3=$(echo "database3=" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^&[]/\\&/g')

sed -i -e '/#variables/i\' -e "$var1\n$var2\n$var3" /data1/create_database
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the number of backslashes since you are operating under double quotes:

```
sed -i "/#variables/i \\
$var1\\
$var2\\
$var3" /data1/create_database
```

And if you have better things to do than count those darned backslashes, you could allow `sed` to take care of the details for you, but it's gonna cost you in terms of code:

```
sed -i "/#variables/{H;s/.*//;x;}
s/\\n/$var1&$var2&$var3&/
" /data1/create_database
```

Or this where no mention of a newline is made:

```
sed -i "/#variables/{
           h
           s/.*/$var1/p
           s/.*/$var2/p
           s/.*/$var3/p
           g
}" /data1/create_database
```

Of course care has to be exercised while planting the shell variables inside sed 
code. They have to be neutered first and then used. Fo example, what if one if your shell vars had a slash '/' in it?